# Почему данные из формы не сохраняются в бд

Tags: django

я вывожу список форм и хочу что б после заполнения данные из них сохранялись в бд

views

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import TaskForm
from .models import Task

# Create your views here.

forms = [];


def save_list(request):
    for form in forms:
        if form.is_valid():
            f = Task.objects.create(title=form.title)
            f.save()
            f.publish()

    return render(request, 'main/save.html', {'forms': Task.objects.all()})  # ищет в templates по дефолту


def task_add(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = TaskForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.cleaned_data()
            form.save()
    else:
        forms.append(TaskForm());
    return render(request, 'main/task_add.html', {'forms': forms})
```

forms

```
from django import forms
from .models import Task


class TaskForm(forms.Form):
    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = ['title']

 #title = forms.CharField(max_length=50);


def save(self):
    new_task = Task.objects.create(self.title)
    return new_task;
```

models

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings


class Task(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def publish(self):
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

HTML

```
{% extends 'main/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
  {% for form in forms %}
<form class="form"method="POST" class="post-form" >

  {{form}}
  <input type="button" value="ok"  class="but" >
  <input type="button" value="add" onClick='location.href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/add"' class="add">
</form>
  {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Откуда у формы метод save? Программа на этом моменте не падает? Никогда не слышал, а вот у [ModelForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method) слышал...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У тебя код абсолютно не правильно написан

1. `forms.py`
   ты переопределяешь метод `save` у формы - зачем(к тому же ты не правильно используешь аттрибуты формы. У формы не будет `self.title`, тебе нужно использовать было `self.cleaned_data['title']`)?
   Замени `forms.Form` на `forms.ModelForm` после этого форма сама автоматически сможет себя сохранять
2. во views.py ты странно используешь глобальную переменную. Ты почему-то решил, что она будет постоянно пополнятся формами при том, как ты вызовешь метод добавить, что абсолютно не так.
3. метод `save_list`
   Ты пробегаешь по всем формам и пытаешься сохранить их, но ты не передаешь им данные которые ввел пользователь(да банально у тебя не будет там форм в этом списке). При сохранении ты должен опираться только на `request.POST` и смотреть по нему сколько форм ввел пользователь.
   Дальше само сохранение ты используешь и `f.save()` и `f.publish()` у тебя метод `publish` идентичен методу `save`, зачем сохранять дважды?

затем ты рендеришь страницу и в нее передаешь списком форм - список объектов Task, ты уж определись, что ты хочешь отдать в шаблон - формы или данные модели и называй переменные соответствующе, а то потом сам не будешь понимать что и где у тебя происходит.

п.с. 4 пункт не верен, я ошибся
4. Дальше, то как ты пишешь формы в шаблоне
Ты выводишь подряд несколько форм (внутри одного тега `<form>...</form>`)
у тебя формы имеют одинаковое название полей и при сохранении ты банально будешь терять часть данных, что бы этого не происходило формируй список форм не просто как массив из форм, а с помощью `formset` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#django.forms.models.BaseModelFormSet

Edit: пример динамического добавления формы на страницу

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">.hidden{ display: none;}</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="hidden form-block">
<hr/>
<form class="form" method="POST" class="post-form" >
  {{form}}
  <input type="button" value="ok"  class="but" >
</form>
</div>
<input id="btn_new" type="button" value="add" class="add">

<script language="Javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#btn_new').bind('click', function(event) {
        let new_block = $('.form-block').clone();
        new_block.removeClass('hidden form-block');
        $('#btn_new').after(new_block);
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

по уму стили вынести отдельно, Javscript отдельно, да и можно было бы обойтись чистым Javascript без `jQuery`.

Comment: Да ,я понял все ошибки ,но не совсем понимаю почему все будет в теге form если я вывожу это через цикл .Вообще я бы хотел реализовать просто две кнопки у поля add и save,add добавляет форму ,save сохраняет  ,как это можно проще всего реализовать?

Comment: По поводу форм я ошибся, не так посмотрел твой код. Они будут каждая по отдельности. Но при таком подходе, у тебя каждая форма будет сохраняться отдельно, поэтому тебе не нужно во view обрабатывать список, обрабатывай только одну форму и ее сохраняй

Comment: просто я не совсем понимаю как реализовать динамическое добавление форм на страницу ,без удаления старых форм

Comment: добавил в ответ пример html страницы(на основе того, что у тебя есть)

Comment: я могу написать на js вопрос что будет происходить при заполнении форм созданных с помощью js

Comment: запрос каждой формы ведет на одну и ту же страницу, поэтому django даже не будет знать отправлена первая или 101 по счету форма. Сохраняться они в таком подходе будут только по одной, если нужно, что было 10 форм и сохранялись разом, то используй `formset`. Там кроме данных формы передаются еще дополнительные параметры, такие как сколько всего форм отправлено + имя параметров каждой формы меняется (например на 'form-0-name', 'form-1-name') и django когда получает такого рода запросы автоматически может их раскидывать по разным формам и соответственно сохранять в разные объекты.

Comment: @ Andrey Maslov спасибо что так подробно отвечаешь на мои тупые вопросы)